# App Registration - Read and Write "All" Site Collections too broad

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

When setting up an Azure App Registration for the Microsoft Graph, the only option is to grant read and write to "ALL" site collections either as delegated or app permissions.   The same is true if using the Office 365 SharePoint Online APIs.

As an ISV creating an multi-tenant application, it raises a red flag for our customer's tenant administrator granting this kind of access when we really only need access to a specific site collection.   Obviously with the SharePoint Add-in (Azure ACS) model the app manifest allowed granting permission at the site level, but in our case we want to take advantage of the Graph API and other APIs backed by Azure App Registration.

I can certainly log granular site collection permissions as a request on UserVoice, but I thought I would check here in case there is some Manifest or querystring magic that can be done to achieve this?

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have moved my question to the Microsoft tech community here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Azure-AD-App-Registration-Permision-request-to-Read-and-Write-to/m-p/40174#M1257

Answer (score 0):

We have a UserVoice for this feature request here. There is no active work on this as yet due to demand so we'd encourage you to vote here. Thank you

https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/34678792-manage-permissions-at-ressource-level-for-sharepoi